# あるカラムの値が同じで、idが連続していないレコードの抽出について

Tags: sql

以下のようなusersテーブルがあるとします。

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | Bob |
| 4 | Carol |
| 5 | Carol |
| 6 | Alice |
| 7 | Dave |

このテーブルからnameが同じで、idが連続していないレコードを抽出したいです。
期待する結果は以下の通りです。

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 6 | Alice |

そのためのクエリや、考え方をご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

「idが連続していないレコードを抽出したい」をより具体的に表現を改めればわかります。
つまり、「あるレコードに対して、nameは一致しid+1となるレコードが存在しない、かつnameは一致しid-1となるレコードが存在しない」が抽出条件なはずです。
そのまま素直にSQLとして記述すれば（テーブル名を`t`とします）、

```
SELECT id, name
FROM t as t0
WHERE
  -- nameは一致しid+1となるレコードが存在しない
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t as t1 WHERE t0.id + 1 = t1.id AND t0.name = t1.name)
AND 
  -- nameは一致しid-1となるレコードが存在しない
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t as t2 WHERE t0.id - 1 = t2.id AND t0.name = t2.name)
```

もう少し効率をよくするなら

```
SELECT id, name
FROM t as t0
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM t as t1
    WHERE (t0.id + 1 = t1.id OR t0.id - 1 = t1.id) AND t0.name = t1.name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 以降であれば CTE(Common Table Expressions) とウィンドウ関数を利用して以下の様に書くことができます。

```sql
WITH users_grouped AS (
    SELECT id, LAG(id) OVER w AS rb, LEAD(id) OVER w AS rn, name
    FROM users
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)
)
SELECT id, name FROM users_grouped WHERE id - rb != 1 OR rn - id != 1;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 6 | Alice |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3vLJMcTE9MEgQ4oWsJibWA/1)